# ES6 symbols with objects Employee with following conditions

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```js
 let email =Symbol();
let Employee = {
  name : "rajesh",
  phone :9800000000,
  [email] : "rajesh@gmail.com"
};
let allKeys = {
  keyss : Reflect.ownKeys(Employee)
};
console.log(allKeys.keyss);
let privateKeys = {
  p : Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(Employee)
};
console.log(privateKeys.p);
let publicKeys = {
  pu : Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Employee)
};
console.log(publicKeys.pu)


module.exports = {Employee, allKeys, privateKeys, publicKeys}
```

**I tried this code in hacker rank for past few days but not passing, I cannot resolve it by my own can any one help me.. 
The question is:

Create an object Employee with properties:

name as "rajesh"
phone as 9800000000,
symbol "email" as "rajesh@gmail.com".

After creating the object, display:

All the keys of object "employee"

Only private keys (symbols)

Only public keys (non symbols)**

Comment: everything looks fine?  runs basically as you would expect?  Symbol('email') maybe?

Comment: What's the test case that is is failing?

Comment: Your export is a bit weird. Why are you storing the key arrays in single-property objects?

Comment: The exports are auto generated in hackerrank

Answer (score 5):

```
let email = Symbol();
let Employee = {
  name : "rajesh",
  phone :9800000000,
  [email] : "rajesh@gmail.com"
};

let allKeys = Reflect.ownKeys(Employee);
let privateKeys = Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(Employee);
let publicKeys =  Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Employee);

module.exports = {Employee, allKeys, privateKeys, publicKeys}
```

Comment: The above code will work. Please check it.                                                                                   Remove {} from let variable after Employee class.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/first-posts/26249142)

Comment: @TusharSapui : Yes. It will work. Also, Object.keys(object) can  return Public Keys.

Answer (score 0):

```
let Employee = {
  name : "rajesh",
  phone :9800000000,
  [Symbol.for('email')] : "rajesh@gmail.com"
};

let allKeys = Reflect.ownKeys(Employee);
let privateKeys = Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(Employee);
let publicKeys =  Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Employee);

module.exports = {Employee, allKeys, privateKeys, publicKeys}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.